# Can't break MySQL table dump into new lines corresponding to table rows

Tags: php, mysql, text

I have a query that dumps a table's data into a text file for reporting purposes. The only problem is that it's not breaking the text file into lines corresponding to the field set in the table. I just get a continuous sequence of data and have to go to the start of what SHOULD be each row, and hit RETURN.

My code is

```
$fh = fopen('dump.txt', 'w');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
     {          
        $last = end($row);          
        $num = mysql_num_fields($result) ;    
           for($i = 1; $i < $num; $i++) 
             {            
               fwrite($fh, $row[$i]);                      
               if ($row[$i] != $last)
               fwrite($fh);
             }                                                                 
        fwrite($fh, "\n");
     }
    fclose($fh);
```

Comment: `fwrite($fh, implode(' ',$row).PHP_EOL);`, no need for mysql_num_fields

Comment: Just tried your 1st suggestion, but got the same result. :(

With fwrite($fh, implode(' ',$row).PHP_EOL); I still don't get new lines, just spaces between all the field contents.

Comment: Maybe use `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.  How do you check the content after creating?

Comment: Yessss! That's it! Thanks a million.

Comment: why do it like this? and why must it be in text format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fh = fopen('dump.txt', 'w');
$exampleData = array(array(1,2,3),array('a','b','c'),array('x','y','z'));
while ($row = array_shift($exampleData)) 
{          
  fwrite($fh, implode(' ',$row).PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($fh);
```

will become

```
1 2 3
a b c
x y z
```

if that not working for you, then there is some other bug to find.

Maybe use `\r\n` instead of just `\n` if you have still problems with line-breaks. PHP_EOL holds `\n` (linux) or `\r\n` (win).